# How do I update extremely old ArcGIS.Client dll's to ArcGISRuntime version 100.7

Tags: migration, esri, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

Recently, my team has inherited an older application and have been tasked with updating the packages that it has. I have three ESRI.ArcGIS.Client dll's that were downloaded into the Visual Studio 2008 solution when the app was created:

ESRI.ArcGIS.Client (version 3.0.0.318)

ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit (version 3.0.0.318)

ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Local (version 1.0.0.3057)

I cannot find documentation anywhere for these versions, and when I use the Nuget Package Manager to download the 100.7, and remove the previous version, I get somewhere around 775 errors, mostly for classes that don't exist in the new versions.

Is there anyone that may have the above mentioned versions' documentation stashed anywhere so I can definitively tell what the classes and methods I have in my application are and/or how i could define them enough to map them to objects, classes, or methods in 100.7?

I have cross posted this on this [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/message/911100-how-to-update-extremely-old-dll-to-1007-sdk) site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Runtime API is an entirely new API built from the ground up.
While you'll probably find some similarities, you're looking mostly at a complete rewrite. Because of this, you won't find a porting tool or a list of "A is renamed to B" list. It's just too different.
The 3.x API was deprecated years ago. I didn't even think the doc site even exists anywhere today, but was lucky to find it with Google: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/apiref/

Comment: that is exactly what i am looking for! I googled for days and didn't find it. Do you mind if i ask what you searched to get that link?

Comment: Don't remember. I think I googled for the DLL name, found the Silverlight doc version, and guessed the WPF version :)

Comment: this had everything i was looking for, except the reference for the ArcGIS.Client.Local